# width: auto; height: 100; and overflow: hidden does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, ng-bootstrap

I have two sets of images as shown below:

[image: side by side images different heights]

The code for both the images is exactly similar. The difference between images in first block and second block is just the dimensions.

So, I want that all the blocks of Images look exactly same height and width. Without considering the dimensions of the image. I also want that width of the image should be 100% of the available width. And height of the image is auto. After setting height of the image to auto If the image's height is greater than its parent's height than that part of image should be hidden.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row top-row">

    <div class="col-md-2">

        <div class="col-md-12 menu-top-wrapper">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" class="menu-top-img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 menu-left-wrapper">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" class="menu-left-img" />            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6  menu-right-wrapper">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" class="menu-right-img" />          
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">

        <div class="col-md-12 menu-top-wrapper">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/900?r=1" class="menu-top-img" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 menu-left-wrapper">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/900?r=2" class="menu-left-img" />            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6  menu-right-wrapper">
            <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/900?r=3" class="menu-right-img" />          
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.menu-left-wrapper {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

.menu-right-wrapper {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}

.menu-top-img {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-left-img {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-right-img {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.img-top-wrapper,
.img-left-wrapper,
.img-right-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-top-img,
.menu-left-img,
.menu-right-img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Here is the JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Vishal1419/s9e8x0pt/

Comment: answer edited....  https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jxbe3ays/

Comment: When it comes to height, are okay with the image being cropped or stretched? I ask because if you don't want either to happen and you have an image that is 400x300 and it's containers height is 100px you might end up with a gap at the bottom depending on the elements width.

Comment: @Vishal .. after dinner time (here).. I have posted a re-edited answer.. take a look

Comment: @Vishal btw, the reason why i set it to 33.5vh is that's the max-space those images seemed to take up..(notice the white space).  i would set the top row equal to 35vh max if you were going to adjust it. I just used 100vh to demonstrate that they would resize equally. Otherwise the top-row will take over the whole height of the screen..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [`object-fit`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) in adjusting your css. like so:

You will note that if you adjust the fiddle output window in height (up or down) that the lower images resize in height, in both blocks equally:

Image 1:[image: Smaller]

Image 2:[image: Bigger]

See code in fiddle and snippet below

```css
.top-row {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1024px;
  overflow: hidden!important;
}

.menu-left-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.menu-right-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.menu-top-img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.img-top-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.img-left-wrapper,
.img-right-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(33.5vh);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu-top-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu-left-img,
.menu-right-img {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px!important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px!important;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(33.5vh);
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row top-row">

    <div class="col-md-2">

      <div class="col-md-12 menu-top-wrapper">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" class="menu-top-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 menu-left-wrapper">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" class="menu-left-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6  menu-right-wrapper">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" class="menu-right-img" />
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">

      <div class="col-md-12 menu-top-wrapper">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/900?r=1" class="menu-top-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 menu-left-wrapper">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/900?r=2" class="menu-left-img" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6  menu-right-wrapper">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/500/900?r=3" class="menu-right-img" />
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

[(Updated) fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/em0b5dnt/)

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I have visited the Fiddle link from your answer. There I can see only one image in second block of images. I want to see three Images there also as shown in first block of images. Can you please take a look at it again?

Comment: you can only see 1 (there is 3) but the overflow is hidden

Comment: I'm currently working on a better solution for you (with percentages)

Comment: Yes the overflow is hidden. But I want to see second block of images as first one. Here is the example of output that I am talking about:  https://in.pinterest.com/jamesh9901/?redirected=1

Comment: Thanks Rachel. You even don't know me still you took time for me. It works great. It is 3 o'clock at night here. I was slept unintentionally. Right now I woke up and show your updated answer. Sorry about that. But I should say big thanks. You saved me many hours of time about figuring out the solution.

Comment: Also, I should mention that to use your code in my scenario I have changed some properties. First one I removed max-width from .top-row, so that I have full space available. Also I changed height: calc(33.5vh); to height 100px; because my Image group will show at the top of the page and I don't want to expand the height of the image. After those changes, I got my required results. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @Vishal happy to help Vishal! :)